# How to remove element from one list by comparing two lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have two Lists, say List1 and List2.
I need to remove elements from List2 if that is already present in List1

To avoid ConCurrentModificationException, I have tried with ListIterator

```
employeeList1 // data present
employeeList2 // data present
ListIterator<Employee> zeroList=employeeList2.listIterator();

//remove employee if already present in list1
while(zeroList.hasNext()){
for(Employee employee : employeeList1){
                    if(zeroList.next().getID().equals(employee.getId())){
zeroList.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am getting the below exception inside the if condition

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

It is possible that element might not be present in List1, but checking the condition is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `removeAll` method on collection from which you want to remove the elements and pass the collection as arguments which contains the elements you want to remove.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("a");
list1.add("b");
list1.add("c");
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("a");
list2.add("p");
list2.add("q");
list2.removeAll(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
```

Removes `a` from list2 as it was present in list1 and prints `p` and `q` only,

```
[p, q]
```

Edit: Here is a sample code for `Employee` class while yours might be a different one but as you said your key is `employeeId` hence `equals` and `hashCode` methods needs to play on `employeeId` only.

```
static class Employee {
    private long employeeId;
    private String name;
    // whatever more variables

    public Employee(long employeeId, String name) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Employee[employeeId=%s, name=%s]", employeeId, name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Employee) {
            return this.employeeId == ((Employee) o).employeeId;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Long(employeeId).hashCode();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Employee> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(new Employee(1, "a"));
    list1.add(new Employee(2, "b"));
    list1.add(new Employee(3, "c"));
    List<Employee> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(new Employee(1, "a"));
    list2.add(new Employee(4, "d"));
    list2.add(new Employee(5, "e"));
    list2.removeAll(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
}
```

Try using this code and see what it prints and then just comment both `equals` and `hashCode` method and then see what happens. After you comment those two methods, the object present in list1 will not be removed as list doesn't know when the two objects are equal.

Comment: My Employee entity contains several variables. So removing via object might not work always. I need to remove based on employeeId

Comment: You can still use the same method even if your list stores custom object. Just make sure you implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` method in your class whose object is stored in your list. And as you are saying based on employeeId, just implement your both methods `equals` and `hashCode` methods based on `employeeId` Can you add the code of your custom class in your post? I'll get you specific pointers then.

Comment: Is it necessary to override hashcode since I am using arraylist here

Comment: small confusion here... I need to remove "a" only from list 2 , not from list 1. Means data present in List 1 should be removed from list2

Comment: Sorry for the little confusion. Overriding only `equals()` method should be enough because you aren't using any `HashMap` or `HashSet` which indeed uses `hashCode()` method. But in general, it is a good practice always to implement both `equals` as well as `hashCode` so that if the object is used somewhere as key in a hashing data structure, it behaves consistent and well.

Comment: @RoseyKhatun: My sample code above in my answer, exactly removes `a` from list2 as `a` is also contained in `list1`. list1 has a b and c and list2 has a p q so when you remove list1 contents from list2, just `a` gets removed and list2 just remains with `p` and `q` only.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the simpler

```
List<Employee> employeeList1
List<Employee> employeeList2

for (Employee employee : employeeList2) {
   if (employeeList1.contains(employee)) {
      employeeList2.remove(employee)
   }
}
```

Of course you would have to synchronize the List calls if using multiple threads.

Comment: My Employee entity contains several variables. So removing via object might not work always. I need to remove based on employeeId

Comment: And if you implement Employee.equals() in a way that employee1.equals(employee2) if employeeIds are equal? Or do you need another equality elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the  [Apache commons-collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html)

library:

```
List<String> newList = ListUtils.union(list1, list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
employeeList1 // data present
employeeList2 // data present
List<Employee> newList = new ArrayList<Empolyee>();
newList.add(employeeList2 );
newList.retainAll(employeeList1);
```

newList will not contain the employeeList1 data.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although this almost solves the problem, could you please explain what your code does so even an unexperienced user can comprehend it? Thanks!